# Make "Files" to sort, columns shown & order PERMANENT

Tags: files, sort

How ought one force Ubuntu Kitty v20 "Files" to *PERMANENTLY*(never changing, **always** the same, nonvolatile) **Sort** in a specific way, and *PERMANENTLY* display certain **Columns** and in a certain column order?

i.e.

[File Size][File Name][File Type **V**][Modified][Permissions]

Comment: What OS/release are you using?   There is no Ubuntu Kitty, no v20, there is Ubuntu Core 20 (*snap* based releases use *yy* format, where as all *deb* based server & desktop releases are *yy.mm* in format). Your question is just unclear, at least to me.  For best results, you should write it as clear & precisely as possible.

Comment: Ubuntu **20**.04.1 LTS https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop know as some kind of kitty

Comment: Ubuntu has many releases, those which are based on *deb* packages are in *yy.mm* format and offered primarily in server & desktop releases. They also provide *snap* based specialist releases such as Ubuntu Core 20 intended for IoT appliances & devices.  Kitty?   Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has the code name *focal fossa* which isn't a cat, but a Fossa (refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossa_(animal) which is mostly related to a mongoose). A fossa is not a cat.  *If you've got a kid, ask them about the Fossa in Madagascar movies*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Files in launcher, select the top bar button with three horizontal bars.  Select "preferences", then click on the "list columns".  From there, select by clicking the button, and drag or use the up/down arrow on the window to rearrange.

---

To change the sort, click on the desired column header of your display. There is a little black triangle to indicate order (ascending, decendnig) --  click again to change the order.

Comment: SWEET! Thank You ubfan1! 95% of what I was looking for,... (am still learning the UI) now to complete the equation, what method can be used to set SORT BY to always display **Type** (descending "v")? it seems sort by "Name" is default.